# Method to find multiple points of a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves

My question is very simple. I want to show the curve

> $$\varphi(t)=((2\cos t+1)\cos t,(2\cos t+1)\sin t)$$

Where $0\le t\le 2\pi$, has multiple points.

The book I'm reading says $P=(0,0)$ is a multiple point such that for every value of $t$ for which $\cos t=\frac{1}{2}$ is taken to $P$ by $\varphi$.

If I didn't know this information beforehand, how can I find the multiple points of this curve?

Comment: I assume you mean $\cos t =-1/2$ ?

Comment: @Kuifje it's written in the book $\cos  t=1/2$

Comment: The book is clearly wrong: if $\cos t = 1/2$, $\phi(t)\neq (0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in polar coordinates, the curve has equation
$$
r= 2\cos \theta+1
$$
So $r=0$ (or equivalently, $P=(0,0)$ is reached) when 
$$
2\cos \theta+1=0 
$$
i.e., when
$$
\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Why must this point be multiple? How to find this point if we didn't know it beforehand? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The point is multiple because the equation $\cos \theta = -1/2$ has more than $1$ solution on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: To find other potential multiple points, you can solve the equation $r(\theta)=R$, for different values of $R$. $P=(0,0)$ is the particular case with $R=0$.